# Проблема с задачей на С++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, код не коректно работает.. Сидел, сидел но в голову ничего не пришло, потому прошу вас помощи.

Условие: Программа должна ввести из консоли натуральное число n и найти предыдущее число к n, что является некоторой степенью двойки.

Код:

```
int func(int index, int ref, int number) {
    int result = 0;
    index = number - 1;
    ref = index;
    while(result == 0) {
        while(index >= 2) {
            index = index / 2;
        }
        if(index == 1) {
            ref--;
            index = ref;
        }
        else {
            result = index;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `int n; cin >> n; cout << pow(2, (int)log2(n)) << endl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу решение через битовый сдвиг:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    int power = 0;
    int res = 1;

    std::cin >> n;

    while ((res << 1) < n) {
        res <<= 1;
        ++power;
    }

    std::cout << res << " = (2^" << power << ")";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Когда вы сдвигаете число на один бит влево (`res <<= 1`), оно умножается на 2. Так как изначальное значение `res` равно 1, то все результаты сдвига будут равны степеням двойки.

Внутри цикла *while* я увеличиваю числа путем возведения в следующую степень двойки, (заодно подсчитывая показатель степени). Условие цикла проверяет, что если число, возведенное в следующую степень уже больше `n`, то можно остановиться и сохранить текущую степень.

**Однако**, если при вводе числа равного одной из степеней двойки вы хотите получить само число, то измените условие на `(res << 1) <= n` - это позволит циклу выполнится еще один раз и увеличить степень на единицу.

Comment: Да спасибо за решения сдвигом битов, а можете мне подсказать что именно в моем решении не так?